# How to save data from JSON to model

Tags: swift, parsing, request

I have an API, I parse it with alomofire, and I want to save parsed json to Model
This is my request and I want to save chats to ChatInstanceModel.
This is my **NetworkingManager** class

```
    func getChatList(completionHandler: (@escaping (ChatInstanceModel) -> Void)) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlOfIntanceAPI) else { return }
        
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization" : "FastToken 8af34fc7c2557517d8a3e747e497de6491a16350df6fa0af8afcbbe72035484efae69d46efa8a47feb75be3250d025b01f42b3b5ad723e5a32afc887c1f6879629b86655ce49e19cada8e289b38d79061160f538c6fa59388076396de1cd2886e2c2e8c5f706ad2bb79a23f034b889c835dd288e44c0cc257d048a22093e51226a60b198bf72aa40a11829771147b4d5"
        ]
        
        AF.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers).responseData { (responseData) in
            switch responseData.result {
            case .success(let data):
                guard let chats = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ChatInstanceModel.self, from: data) else { return }
                
                completionHandler(chats)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my model:

```
struct ChatInstanceModel: Codable {
    let title: String
    let avatar: String?
    let unread_client: Int?
}
```

This is api which I want to save

```
{
    "pk": 3,
    "title": "None",
    "avatar": null,
    "unread_client": 0,
    "unread_manager": 0,
    "is_online": false,
    "is_typing": false,
    "last_seen": null,
    "manager": null,
    "last_update": null
}
```

Comment: Show more code where you want to use the parsed object i.e, `chat`? Show the use of `completionHandler`?

Comment: this completionHandler will be used in other class

Comment: Did you try that? Did you create a `class` level member/property to assign the parsed value? It will be difficult to help without seeing the actual code.

Comment: What's the exact issue are you facing in this as parsing seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can save the `ChatInstanceModel` instance after the getting the response from API using the `completionHandler`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var chats: ChatInstanceModel?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getChatList { (chats) in
            self.chats = chats
        }
    }
}
```

That's just a simple example for your problem statement currently specified.

Answer (score 0):

Please find an example:

```swift
import Alamofire

// Your Model
struct ChatInstanceModel: Codable {
    let title: String
    let avatar: String?
    let unread_client: Int?
}

// Your View Controller
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Your chat instance
    var chats: ChatInstanceModel? = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getChatList { (chats) in
            self.chats = chats
            print(self.chats?.title)
        }
        
    }

    // Get chat list from api
    func getChatList(completionHandler: (@escaping (ChatInstanceModel) -> Void)) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "<API_URL>") else { return }
        
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization" : "<TOKEN>"
        ]
        
        let request = AF.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers)
        request.responseDecodable(of: ChatInstanceModel.self) { (dataResponse) in
            
            switch dataResponse.result {
            
            case .success(let data):
                completionHandler(data)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error", error.localizedDescription)
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).